# how make a button to bring up mainform from splashform (c#)?

Tags: c#

```
 public partial class SplashForm : Form
  {
    private Dictionary<string, string> _soundEffectsDict;    
    public SplashForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _soundEffectsDict = new Dictionary<string, string>(); // make a list..
        _soundEffectsDict.Add("game", @".\Sounds\game.wav");    
    }

    private void splashQuitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void splashPlayButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Run(new hauntedHouse());  //this is the part that won't work
    }
  }
```

Comment: Show the `hauntedHouse` code please, the following link explains pretty much all you want https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ws1btzy8%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: Also `InitializeComponent` for this form, or at least an abbreviated excerpt to prove that the evenst are being hooked up correctly..

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't show your main form *from* splash screen. You should close your splash screen first.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DialogResult dr;

        using (var splash = new SplashForm())
        {
            dr = splash.ShowDialog();
        }
        if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Application.Run(new HauntedHouse());
        }
    }
}
```

Let's assume that your "play" button setups DialogResult to OK. Otherwise, you can maintain a property in SplashForm or pass the decision whether to quit or continue by other way

Answer (score 0):

You could show splashform as a dialog from a hauntedHouse_Load event handler.